In beamer, can I set a left column over a right column?
I have a beamer frame with two columns. The left column has text and the right column has an image. Some of the text sticks out on the right of the left column, and the image on the right obscures that overlapping text.
Rather than reflow the text (it's an equation), I'd like the text overlapping from the left column to appear on top of the image in the right column.
This can be done in the opposite order, for the simple reason that the box containing the left column is placed on the page before the box containing the right column. So if the text were on the right, and overlapped, it would appear over an image on the left. Is there a clean way to set the column boxes in the other order?
Here is a MWE.
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Right overlaps left}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \makebox[\columnwidth][r]{
            looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Can we make left overlap right?}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \makebox[\columnwidth][l]{
            looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}




You don't need to load graphicx with beamer

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Good point, thanks! I could have made my MWE one line shorter.

Probably a bit overkill, but you could use the tikzmark library to smuggle your image into the background canvas:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=west] at (pic cs:quack) {\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Right overlaps left}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \makebox[\columnwidth][l]{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \tikzmark{quack}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}



\tikzmark is a clever idea. It seems like we can put \tikzpicture inside the frame environment too instead of changing the background.

@MatthewLeingang Indeed, you'll just need to use it before the columns

@MatthewLeingang Instead of using columns, you could also place two nodes next to each other.
